# Open .css as .less file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: css, intellij-idea, less

I have a **.css** file in IntelliJ IDEA, but it has a **LESS** content.

This is why IntelliJ IDEA shows errors when it analyzes the correctness of the **.css** file:

- > Unknown CSS at-rule

  [image: Unknown CSS at-rule]
- > a term expected

  [image: a term expected]

Changing the file extension is not a solution because it's not my own project.

How can I force IntelliJ IDEA to open the .css files as .less files in order to be able to recognize LESS tricks (E.g.: `@xyz: 100px;`)?

**Details**

- IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2016.2
- Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **File Types** > **Less** > Add *.css > **OK** > **Reassign wildcard** > **OK**

[image: Add]

[image: Add .css extension]

[image: Reassign wildcard]